# Google and Landing Pages

Tags: seo, google, landing-page

Some time ago (about 12 months) I created a number of targeted pages for our main product site.  Out main product can be called several different things and clearly it's not possible to optimize our home page for all of them so we created new pages called 'secondary-term-1.htm' and 'secondary-term-2.htm'.  These contained unique content and at the time I linked to them our site map and our blog.  And that was it.

A year later these pages are now ranking quite well and I want to expand on this concept and create new landing pages for other terms.  I believe these landing pages are useful to people searching using different terms and relating this back to our product. I also think they are useful in explaining how our product is useful to different market segments.

What is the current thinking with respect to Google as far as these landing pages go?  Are we likely to be penalized in some way?  This site is our main money maker and I am ultra cautious with what we can and cannot do on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stick with Google guidelines you will be fine. If you have 5 pages targeting different terms about the same thing and their content is different there will be no problem; if you create 100 pages, copy-paste content and then replace just the keyword, maybe you will get in troubles.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The Google definition on 'doorway pages' is a little vague.  Do you think the sort of pages I have been talking about could ever be construed as 'doorway' pages?

Comment: If each one of these pages are useful for your users, add enough valuable content and can be reached from your navigation, probably they won't be treated as doorway pages.

Comment: I've said navigation, but not necessarily, if they can be reached from other pages, they are included in your internal site linking structure then you are doing right things.

Comment: All pages are reachable via the site map, usually via a js menu system (I know some spiders don't do js), and usually via a post on the weblog.  Sounds like I should be fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you kidding? This is exactly what Google wants! 
They want their searchers to get the best results. Just make sure the content is unique on each page. Also monitor the stats to learn more from your visitors. Be consistent in adding your pages. That means, don't publish 4 pages om the first of the month. Publish 1 page each week. Consistency matters. Google then knows your serious about the website.

Comment: Thanks.  Site is 5 years old, there's a blog with more than 500 entries, been adding one or two a week for a long time.  Static pages are added less frequently but my blog publishes static files anyway so there really shouldn't be too much difference.